# How do you pass data between VueJS components when using the Vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have these routes setup:

```
Vue.use(Router)
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/group/:id',
      name: 'Group',
      component: GroupContainer,
      children: [
        {
          // when /group/:id/posts is matched
          path: 'posts',
          component: ViewPosts
        },
        {
          // when /group/:id/topics is matched
          path: 'topics',
          component: ViewTopics
        },
        {
          // when /group/:id/people is matched
          path: 'people',
          component: ViewPeople
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

So the group component has a template with the router view here

```
<template>
  <div class="group">
    I am a group page
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

So the group component ends up being the parent to the ViewPosts, ViewTopics, or ViewPeople, but, it doesn't directly contain the components.

What is a good system to pass data from the parent (Group) to the children (ViewPosts...) and allow the children to emit up to the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to add the properties and handlers to the `router-view`.

```
<div class="group">
  I am a group page
  <router-view :topics="topics"
           :people="people"
           :posts="posts"
           @topic-emitted="onTopicEmitted">
  </router-view>
</div>
```

Here is a quick [example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/XMGpaZ?editors=1010).

Comment: @ben You;re welcome :) I wouldn't typically do this, but this was your first question; if the answer helped you/answered your question, you typically should upvote or accept the answer, or both. Entirely up to you though.